# Viewing SQLite3 Database (XCODE)

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am creating an iphone app within XCODE the makes use of an SQLite3 database.  I am creating the database programmatically if it does not exist.  I am not getting any errors when I run the program.

How can I check the contents of the database to ensure that the data has been inserted correctly into the correct columns?  Where does Xcode place the table within my system where I can view it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The SQLite database will be created in your apps `Documents` folder, in the simulator's base directory.

**Before Xcode 6**, you can check in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/GUID/Documents
```

There is also a Mac OS X application called [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) that you can use to browse the database your app created.

### Update :

As of Xcode 6, the new iOS simulator's directory is located here :

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`

Ultimately, you can find your app's database under a location like this (Replace UIDs by yours) :
`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D2D127A-7103-41B2-872B-2DB891B978A2/data/Containers/Data/Application/0323215C-2B91-47F7-BE81-EB24B4DA7339/Documents/MyApp.sqlite`

*Source: [SO: Xcode 6 iPhone Simulator Application Support Location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24291087/3515052)*

Comment: The simulator directory has been moved with Xcode 6 to: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`. To find the unique path add the following statement to the `AppDelegate.m` file `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method: `NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] `
   `URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  `
     `inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);`

Comment: You're right @Brabbeldas, I added the new Xcode 6's simulator folder as an edit to the original answer so it is more pertinent.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to view the database that you are created,

Open finder press Command+g "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" then go.

Open 5.0 (as per your version of simulator)-> Application-> select the pgm folder

-> Documents

[image]

Then you can see the database

[image]

Comment: The simulator directory has been moved with Xcode 6 to: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`. To find the unique path add the following statement to the `AppDelegate.m` file `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method: `NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] `
   `URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  `
     `inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);`

Answer (score 1):

The simulator directory has been moved with Xcode 6 to: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`. To find the unique path add the following statement to the `AppDelegate.m` file, `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method:

`NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);`

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 9.1:**

1. Open Terminal, type:

   cd ~ & find -name "YourModelName.sqlite"
2. You'll most likely be presented with such a path:

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY/Library/Application
>   Support/

3. Open Finder, press Shift + Command + G, paste the path and press Go.
4. Use [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org) to view the .sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of standalone programs that look at sqllite files.  A very popular one for the Mac is called "Base":

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base/id402383384?mt=12

Comment: Base is not free, SQLiteBrowser is free.

Comment: I should have mentioned Base is not free, but it is MUCH nicer than SQLLiteBrowser (which I used for years).