# Where is my app's com.company.app.plist after the app is installed to the iOS 8 Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

For my 7.1 and 7.1-64 Simulators, an application's com.company.app.plist file is stored in its "Preferences" folder under the following path:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/<some id>/Library/Preferences/com.company.app.plist`
```

**Question:** Where is the com.company.app.plist file stored for an application installed on the iOS 8 simulator?

**To be clear:** I'm looking for the .plist that stores the application's NSUserDefaults. On iOS 7.X, this was the com.company.app.plist at the above path.

**This is not in the folder where my Application's data is stored.** I've found the `.sqlite` files associated with my app, but I cannot find the `.plist` that contains the `NSUserDefault` values I'm interested in

Comment: This... didn't answer my question. I'm not looking for my app's data. I'm looking for where the application's NSUserDefaults are located. This is not located under `/Users/{YOUR NAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APPLICATION ID}` as both answers suggest.

Comment: The location for the preferences plist for the XCode 6 simulator running iOS 8.1 is ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<your simulator's device UUID>/data/Applications/<your app UUID>/Library/Preferences/<bundle-id>.plist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290989/xcode-6-iphone-simulator-application-support-location