# Location of Sqlite file location of CoreData iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am developing an iOS application with Objective-C and CoreData. Where can I locate the sqlite file generated on the iOS device?

Comment: sqlite file wil be in the app sandbox for a device!!!

Comment: you can log the document directory path within the code!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 iPhone Simulator Application Support location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290989/xcode-6-iphone-simulator-application-support-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the store uses a persisted file, you can even get it in code

```
//get you context, the coordinator, attached stores
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [MyDataStore sharedDataStore].mainManagedObjectContext; //however you get the MOC
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = moc.persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSArray<NSPersistentStore*> *stores = coordinator.persistentStores;

//log it
for (NSPersistentStore *store in stores) {
    NSLog(@"%@", store.URL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For XCode 8.0 (iOS 10)**

Path to the persistent store created by NSPersistentContainer can be seen by adding following code in existing (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) method in your AppDelegate:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    print(urls[urls.count-1] as URL) // look for doc. directory

    return true
}
```

Go to the path in the print log then go to the /Library/Application Support folder. Here is the sample path of .sqlite(persistent store) file:

/Users/Ashish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F04D26BC-0AA9-4E25-87CC-E635BE86293A/data/Containers/Data/Application/69873117-6AB0-4491-B3BA-302FE63050FB/Library/Application Support

Answer (score 0):

It's wherever you decided to put it. You don't even need to look it up, because you already have that information.

When you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`, the **`URL`** argument that you pass in is the location of the persistent store. You **could** look it up by the `NSManagedObjectContext` and the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, but why do that when the answer is already there in your app?